# How to efficiently aggregate big Redis ordered sets?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, redis

To be honest this is more of a thought experiment or an algorithmic challenge.
I am curious if the leaderboard system I created in Redis could be scaled beyond capacity of 1 server node.

Leaderboard entry is a `key`, `score` pair stored in an Order Set(ZSET).
Entries are added to random set that are chosen from key's hashcode, effectively sharding the data.

The leaderboard supports many types of queries and I was able to efficiently implement all of them in a sharded variant(which probably won't be used in production), except for one.

I want to implement iteration that returns ordered entries given `skip` and `limit` arguments.
Getting first, say, 10 elements is easy: I request biggest 10 entries from each shard, and I aggregate the sets while sorting it, then keep the top 10 elements from aggregated set.
However, this becomes very inefficient the deeper we want to go into the leaderboard with `skip`.

Question:

1. Is there a way to satisfy this query in a logarithmic time?
2. Is there metadata I can create during insert that would help satisfy such query? Hopefully increasing insert time from O(1) to O(log n) max?

Answer (score 2):

First, you'll want a new command that isn't directly in https://redis.io/commands/?group=sorted-set.  Which is what the rank of a given element with a given score WOULD be if it were in the set (which it might be).

You can do that by checking whether the element is there with that score.  If it is, then return its rank.  If it isn't there, then insert it, find its rank, and delete it.  If it is there with the wrong score, delete it, insert it with the new score, find its rank, delete it, insert it with the right score.

All this can be bundled in a LUA command, which will be fast and atomic.

Now your problem would be easier if you can just return what the last element was, and where it is in the set.  Because you can discover its rank, then fetch the next 10 elements, merge, and return them.

If you insist on just indicating the page, you can do a binary search as follows.  Take the element from one of the sorted sets at a chosen rank.  Then find its overall rank across all shards.  Then decide what to do next.  With a straightforward binary search you'll need to make `O(log(n))` requests across the cluster.  If you're clever about asking for elements close to where you think the answer is, you can reduce this to an average of `O(log(log(n)))` requests at the expense of sometimes needing many extras.  (Tip, keep track of the rank range for each shard, and always ask for an element by rank from the shard with the largest range.  Any shard whose range is down to 0 elements stops being part of your range.)